# Redirection for IE in static website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to redirect to new html page when the website opens in IE 8 and below versions of IE. 
MY website is full static html.

I need solution to redirect my website to a new page.

Comment: Define *it's flickering*

Comment: What is going on with that meta tag? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never seen that method before. This is how I'd do it:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.location = '77ebrowser.html'</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a refresh in your http-equiv attribute, and make sure it's defined in your head tag.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.whatever"/>
<![endif]-->
```